# UBL-XML Validating with Schematron

Tags: xml, xslt, schematron

I have two XML files, good and bad. I need to validate these with an XML Schematron file. The Schematron file I am asked to validate is an XML with SCH tags. I was able to convert this XML file to an XSL file with the help of Oxygen XML, but I think there are different XSLS called iso XSL and SVRL XSL.

How should I go about it?

The validation method:

```cs
public static ValidationResult SchematronValidateXml(List<XmlDocument> xmlList)
{
    var result = new ValidationResult();
    foreach (var document in xmlList)
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(document.OuterXml));
        var resultStream = XslTransformer.Transform(reader);

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(resultStream))
        {
            bool hasError = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("svrl:text");
            while (hasError)
            {
                string id = "";
                var elementId = (XmlElement)document.GetElementsByTagName("cbc:ID")[0];
                if (elementId != null)
                    id = elementId.InnerText;

                result.ErrorMessageList.Add("Schematron (" + id + ") :" + xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                hasError = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("svrl:text");
            }
        }
    }

    result.IsValid = !result.ErrorMessageList.Any();
    return result;
}
```

The transformer method:

```cs
public static Stream Transform(XmlTextReader xmlTextReader)
{
    try
    {
        var processor = new Processor();
        var input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(xmlTextReader);

        var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        var xslTextReader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Tools\Schematron\Schematron.xsl");
        var transformer = compiler.Compile(xslTextReader).Load();
        transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

        var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
        var serializer = processor.NewSerializer(resultStream);

        transformer.Run(serializer);

        resultStream.Position = 0;
        return resultStream;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear which XSLT based Schematron implementation you are using or want to use. For XSLT 2 or 3 you can use Schxslt, latest 1.5.1 release at https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt/releases/tag/v1.5.1 explained in https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt/tree/v1.5.1#readme. Or there is the no longer maintained https://github.com/Schematron/schematron. As for running, if you want to validate several XML documents against the same Schematron schema, consider to pass that once through e.g. `pipeline-for-svrl.xsl` and cache the result to be compiled once with XsltCompiler into an XsltExecutable.

Comment: You can also validate your XML using the Schematron inside Oxygen. See https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/22.1/ug-editor/topics/validating-XML-documents-against-schema.html#validating-XML-documents-against-schema